# displaying results from a search laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query that displays results according to a such term

```
 public function search(Request $request){
     $foodsAll = Restaurant::whereHas('foods',function($query) use ($request){
         $query->where('food_item','like','%'.$request->q.'%');
     })->get();
     return view('restaurants.searchShow')->with(['foodsAll'=>$foodsAll]);
 }
```

I am displaying the results in a blade `searchShow`

```
<html>            
<ul>
    @foreach($restaurants as $restaurant)
        <li>{{$restaurant->name}}</li> 
    @endforeach
</ul>
</html>
```

I get the error

> Undefined variable: restaurants (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tafuta_restaurant\resources\views\restaurants\searchshow.blade.php)

Comment: As the error clearly states, `$restaurants` is undefined, as you never defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send "foodsAll" from Controller and iterate "restaurants" in view  how it work???
change to..

```
   @foreach($foodsAll as $restaurant)
     <li>{{$restaurant->name}}</li> 
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending a `$restaurants` variable to your view, you called it `$foodsAll`.

Either change your view to the following:

```
@foreach($foodsAll as $restaurant)
    <li>{{$restaurant->name}}</li> 
@endforeach
```

Or change the name of the variable you send to your view.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided above, seems like you are either passing wrong variable to you view or you are trying to loop from wrong variable inside your view.

Change this:

```
@foreach($restaurants as $restaurant)
```

To this:

```
@foreach($foodsAll as $restaurant)
```